# Passing data when you click a button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I have several buttons next to different types of textboxes throughout the window that run the same type of flow.  I have decided to clump all the _click events into one event by adding comma delimiters with Handles.  Is there a way to tell which button was clicked through some property so that I could enable only those specific textfields using a case statement or something to that extent?  Since it's all handled through one click event(since i didnt want to make 10+ click events just to run the same function that the other buttons run, save code and readability) is there some way to find out which button was clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate you've got two arguments: Object sender, and EventArgs e.
Just cast sender object onto the button object, and then you can cope with a button and its all properties:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            string name = btn.Name;
        }
```

EDIT: I'm sorry, didn't notice the VB.NET tag, but I'll leave my answer just in case;)

Comment: This could easily be converted into VB code. To me, this looks correct!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Public Sub YourEventHandlerName(sender As object, e As EventArgs)
    Select CType(sender, Button).Name
        Case "Button1_Name"
            'Do what ever you wanted to do in here
        Case "Button2_Name"
            'Do what ever you wanted to do in here
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, if this is the actual thought of usage, I'd rather see an event handler for each button. That is way cleaner and a lot easier to maintain. 
This way, you're stuck with hard-coded names as strings...